# mswjs testing RTK query how to add data to the request

Tags: testing, rtk-query

I'm using mswjs to mock data

for my query api with RTK query.

All works fine, but I'm stuck to handle
a mutation that updates the list of my items.

My handlers

```
const handlers = [
    rest.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/post`, (req, res, ctx) => {
        const mockApiResponse = {
            itesms: []
        };
        return res(ctx.json(mockApiResponse));
    }),
    rest.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/post`, (req, res, ctx) => {
        const mockApiResponse = {
            text: 'My new item'
        };
        return res(ctx.json(mockApiResponse));
    })
];
```

So in my test, I fill the form
and submit it then I'd like to check
if an item is added to the list.
Is there a way to refresh the state?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a persisting state for you data you have to create that by yourself. The easiest way to do so is to keep the state as a higher-scoped variable, like `state`, mutating it in the respective request handlers.

```js
const state = {
  posts: []
}

export const handlers = [
  rest.post('/api/post', (req, res, ctx) => {
    const newPost = req.body
    state.posts.push(newPost)
    return res(ctx.json(newPost))
  }),

  rest.get('/api/post', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json(state.posts))
  })
]
```

Overall, you can use any approach to your liking: a global state, a state management library, a client-side database like IndexDB, etc. MSW is not opinionated in that regard as it doesn't deal with the data state.

We do have [@mswjs/data](https://github.com/mswjs/data) library that allows you to *model* your data and it generates request handlers for you. With this approach, you do get data persistence and mutations out of the box but you need to be okay with the model-driven data mocking.